# xcode refuse to run application on iphone something about private key

Tags: xcode4, private-key

I spent one full week trying to get over this problem but nothing appears to help me.

I use to have a MacBook Pro, and I used it to connect my iphone devices and deploy my iOS applications on it. Now I have bought an new Mac Book pro, when I try to test some applications on my new iPhone using my new Mac, it just refuse to accept it or accept any of my old devices I registered on my old MAC.

It just report : "Code Signature error". I found in the device organizer >> iphone >> Provisioning profile in the status of "valid singing identity is not found"

From my reading and trying, I think the problem is that my new Mac seems to not bet able to get the private key of my team. However, I don't know how to get this key from my old Mac, and I don't know - if it possible - how to get new key for my new Mac.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution in this link:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/90538-critical-back-up-your-developer-key.htm

I manage to archive my old Private key from my old Mac and installed it again on my new one and everything went perfect :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that your certificates are present in the new Mac's keyChain ? (should if you initialized from a time machine). If they are not, export the certificates on the old mac with the keychain utility. Later import them in the new mac's keychain.

Look for certificates whose name begins with iPhone developer and iPhone distribution.

Comment: Yes I have the two of them at the login section.